# Read different types of clipboard data with ctypes in python

Tags: python, windows, clipboard, ctypes

I have this code that gets the windows clipboard data (in text) with ctypes using `CF_UNICODETEXT` in `GetClipboardData` function.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes as w

CF_UNICODETEXT = 13
CF_HDROP = 15

u32 = ctypes.windll.user32
k32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

OpenClipboard = u32.OpenClipboard
OpenClipboard.argtypes = w.HWND,
OpenClipboard.restype = w.BOOL
GetClipboardData = u32.GetClipboardData
GetClipboardData.argtypes = w.UINT,
GetClipboardData.restype = w.HANDLE
GlobalLock = k32.GlobalLock
GlobalLock.argtypes = w.HGLOBAL,
GlobalLock.restype = w.LPVOID
GlobalUnlock = k32.GlobalUnlock
GlobalUnlock.argtypes = w.HGLOBAL,
GlobalUnlock.restype = w.BOOL
CloseClipboard = u32.CloseClipboard
CloseClipboard.argtypes = None
CloseClipboard.restype = w.BOOL


def get_clipboard_text():
    text = ""
    if OpenClipboard(None):
        h_clip_mem = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT)
        text = ctypes.wstring_at(GlobalLock(h_clip_mem))
        GlobalUnlock(h_clip_mem)
        CloseClipboard()
    return text


print(get_clipboard_text())
```

`CF_HDROP` is supposed to return a list of files copied to the clipboard,
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats) but I can't get it to work.

How can I get this code to return a files list and not only text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `CF_HDROP` format is available, you can use `DragQueryFile()` to first tell you how many files are present. Then you you can call it once per entry to obtain the filename. For example:

```
import sys
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes as w

CF_HDROP = 15

u32 = ctypes.windll.user32
k32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
s32 = ctypes.windll.shell32

OpenClipboard = u32.OpenClipboard
OpenClipboard.argtypes = w.HWND,
OpenClipboard.restype = w.BOOL

GetClipboardData = u32.GetClipboardData
GetClipboardData.argtypes = w.UINT,
GetClipboardData.restype = w.HANDLE

CloseClipboard = u32.CloseClipboard
CloseClipboard.argtypes = None
CloseClipboard.restype = w.BOOL

DragQueryFile = s32.DragQueryFile
DragQueryFile.argtypes = [w.HANDLE, w.UINT, ctypes.c_void_p, w.UINT]


def get_file_list():
    files = []
    
    if OpenClipboard(None):
        h_hdrop = GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP)
        
        if h_hdrop:
            FS_ENCODING = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
            file_count = DragQueryFile(h_hdrop, -1, None, 0)

            for index in range(file_count):
                buf = ctypes.c_buffer(260)
                DragQueryFile(h_hdrop, index, buf, ctypes.sizeof(buf))
                files.append(buf.value.decode(FS_ENCODING))

    CloseClipboard()
    return files
    
print(get_file_list())
```

So if you now select some files in Windows Explorer and use `Copy`, the script should return the file list.