# readLines from clipboard encoding woes

Tags: r, encoding, emacs

On a previous question, I highlighted some text from the question and wanted to do something with it in R. The text,

```
2021-12-14T19:49:28.322136+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ✔ ggplot2 3.3.3     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
```

has non-ascii characters. If I paste that directly into R, it is displayed correctly:

[image]

While this screenshot is of emacs/ESS, it does the same in RStudio *here*; the second half of this question is about displaying a string with checkmarks, which works in RStudio but not in emacs/ESS.

### reading from the clipboard

If I try to copy it with `readLines` or `read.table` or similar, it does not preserve the checkmarks (among other things in other strings):

```r
readLines("clipboard")
# Warning in readLines("clipboard") :
#   incomplete final line found on 'clipboard'
# [1] "2021-12-14T19:49:28.322136+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ? ggplot2 3.3.3     ? purrr   0.3.4"
```

I've tried `encoding="UTF-8"` and `"latin1"` and even `"cp866"` (a random attempt from another question, no I do not need cyrillic) and nothing preserves the checkmarks. Can somebody help with a canonical method for doing this (on windows)?

To see if it is a clipboard-munging thing, I tested against two bits of *python* code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66065722/3358272 produces the same behavior as R (i.e., `✔` to `?`), but https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-programming/ctypes-bug-cannot-copy-data-to-clipboard-via-python/td-p/9195866 *works correctly*. That discovery lends credence to the existence of a workaround in R.

Basic system info:

```r
sessionInfo()
# R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
```

Currently emacs-26.3, ess-18.10.3snapshot [elpa: 20211011.2049].

### displaying the string correctly

Side note about the differences between emacs/ESS and the RStudio IDE: in RStudio, I can embed the string in double-quotes and it is displayed correctly,

```r
> "2021-12-14T19:49:28.322136+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ✔ ggplot2 3.3.3     ✔ purrr   0.3.4"
[1] "2021-12-14T19:49:28.322136+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ✔ ggplot2 3.3.3     ✔ purrr   0.3.4"
```

yet in emacs/ESS it is not:

```r
> "2021-12-14T19:49:28.322136+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]: ✔ ggplot2 3.3.3     ✔ purrr   0.3.4"
[1] "2021-12-14T19:49:28.322136+00:00 shinyapps[5326981]:   ggplot2 3.3.3       purrr   0.3.4"
```

I'm not interested in changing my muscle-memory from emacs/ESS to RStudio, so I'd appreciate help in emacs/ESS-specific display issues here as well.

Comment: Just guessing here, but I'd bet this has something to do with [Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats) or the way it accesses the "clipboard" in Msoft Win. Maybe Win sets it in something ASCII, so that changing it to utf-8 later doesn't do anything anymore.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, I hadn't considered that. However, if I *just* copy from a browser and paste directly (into R, powerpoint, word, ...), then the checkmarks are preserved, suggesting it is not a clipboard-induced change.

Comment: Maybe the platform dependent `'clipboard'` in Win does something special, different from the normal copy/paste. The c sources should give some more insight.

Comment: Btw, try `library("clipr")` and check if that works.

Comment: Thanks, nope: `clipr::read_clip()` still changes `✔` to `?`.

Comment: I see the same behaviour as Rstudio in ESS(18.10.3snapshot) on emacs(29.0.50) with R 3.6.3 on Ubuntu - ie. the checkmarks are displayed as expected. I'm guessing this is Windows specific, but to be thorough, what are your emacs/ess versions? –

Comment: Currently emacs-26.3, ess-18.10.3snapshot [elpa: 20211011.2049] (on windows 10).